# Optical Microscope change in color of image

Tags: optics, microscopy

Is it possible for the numerical aperture to change the color of the image of an optical microscope?

The first image is an image with 50x magnification, using a .95 NA.

The second image is an image with 10x magnification, using a .3 NA.

The image of the microscope turns from a light purple to a light blue, if I change the magnification. Is this due to the different wavelengths not being able to enter the microscope when I change the magnification?

[image: 50x Magnification]

[image: 10x Magnification]

Comment: (1) your images are not of the same area, so who knows what the 'real' color should be. (2) How high a quality color sensor do you have? Read the specs.

Comment: @Jon it is the same area, just with different magnification (as far as I can see, the center of the images are the same)

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Quite a difference in magnification. Have you also looked at the specs on the different lenses being used? And, are you using polarization for imaging?

Comment: No polarization was used and the specs are as I listed! No oil immersion or etc.

Comment: If you magnify the second image, you will see purple at the center...

Comment: Its just the different glasses and quantity used for the 2 different objectives. If you look at the camera specifications you will also probably see that both images have different settings of exposure and ISO.
Simple answer: No, NA does not change color.
Long answer: the different glass elements of the 2 different objectives will have different visibile light transmission profiles, giving a hue to the image.